# y2tics and y2label missing in the pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a pm3d map using both the primary and secondary axes of gnuplot (version 5.2 patchlevel 8). However, the y2label is missing and the y2tics do not appear after three marks. It would be very helpful if anyone can kindly point out any mistake I have made. The script used is given below and the figure obtained is attached for your reference.Thank you in advance.

```
set term postscript
set output "map.ps"
set pm3d map corners2color c1
set palette maxcolors 8
set palette defined (0 "#FFFFFF",  1 "#FFFF00",  2 "#FFC020",  3 "#FF69B4",  4 "#4169E1",  5 "#008000",  6 "#20B2AA",  7 "#9ACD32")
set lmargin at screen 0.095
set rmargin at screen 0.795
unset key

# set x-axis                                           
#*******************************************************
set xlabel "Time (ns)" font "Times-italic,18" offset 0, -0.5, 0
set xrange [0.000: 7500.000]
set xtics ("0" 0.000, "50" 1250.0, "100" 2500.0, "150" 3750.0, "200" 5000.0, "250" 6250.0, "300" 7500.0) font "Times-italic,16"

# set y-axis                                         
#*******************************************************
set ylabel "Peptide Number" font "Times-italic,18" offset -1.2, 1, 0
set yrange [2.0: 36.0]
set ytics ("1" 5.0,  "2" 12.0,  "3" 19.0,  "4" 26.0,  "5" 33.0) font "Times-italic,16"
set ytics nomirror
set y2label "Residue Number" font "Times-italic,18" offset -2.5, 0, 0 
set y2range [2.0: 36.0]
set y2tics nomirror ("1" 2.0,  "7" 8.0, "1" 9.0 , "7" 15.0, "1" 16.0,  "7" 22.0,  "1" 23.0, "7" 29.0,  "1" 30.0,  "7" 36.0) font "Times-italic,14"

# set cb-axis                                          
#*******************************************************
set colorbox vertical user origin 0.890, .147 size .04, .73
set cbrange [-0.500: 7.500]
set cbtics 0.000, 7.000, 1.0
set cbtics("None"    0.000,"Ext"    1.000,"Bridge"    2.000,"3-10"    3.000,"Alpha"    4.000,"Pi"    5.000,"Turn"    6.000,"Bend"    7.000)

set link y2
splot "-" with pm3d title "map.gnu"
```

1.000    1.000             2
1.000    2.000             0
1.000    3.000             0
1.000    4.000             0
1.000    5.000             0
1.000    6.000             3
1.000    7.000             0
1.000    8.000             0
1.000    9.000             0
1.000   10.000             0
1.000   11.000             0
1.000   12.000             0
1.000   13.000             0
1.000   14.000             1
1.000   15.000             0
1.000   16.000             0
1.000   17.000             6
1.000   18.000             0
1.000   19.000             7
1.000   20.000             0
1.000   21.000             0
1.000   22.000             4
1.000   23.000             0
1.000   24.000             0
1.000   25.000             6
1.000   26.000             6
1.000   27.000             5
1.000   28.000             0
1.000   29.000             0
1.000   30.000             4
1.000   31.000             0
1.000   32.000             0
1.000   33.000             7
1.000   34.000             0
1.000   35.000             0
1.000   36.000 0

2.000    1.000             0
2.000    2.000             0
2.000    3.000             0
2.000    4.000             2
2.000    5.000             4
2.000    6.000             5
2.000    7.000             0
2.000    8.000             0
2.000    9.000             6
2.000   10.000             0
2.000   11.000             0
2.000   12.000             0
2.000   13.000             7
2.000   14.000             0
2.000   15.000             0
2.000   16.000             0
2.000   17.000             0
2.000   18.000             0
2.000   19.000             8
2.000   20.000             0
2.000   21.000             0
2.000   22.000             0
2.000   23.000             0
2.000   24.000             9
2.000   25.000             6
2.000   26.000             6
2.000   27.000             6
2.000   28.000             0
2.000   29.000             5
2.000   30.000             0
2.000   31.000             0
2.000   32.000             0
2.000   33.000             7
2.000   34.000             0
2.000   35.000             0
2.000   36.000 0

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can reproduce your issue but don't have a solution yet. You are plotting the special file `'-'`, i.e. your data should follow the code. Could you please edit your question and show a few lines example data? Just to see how the structure of your data looks like. Certainly `x,y,z`, but with or without single/double empty lines, etc.? Maybe there is a way to plot it with `plot` instead of `splot` to avoid this issue.

Comment: Yes Sir. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for adding minimal example data. So, I assume the format is `y, x, z`, correct? Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your code that you have simple `x,y,z` data.

- `x` with sample numbers from 0 to 7500 which correspond to 0 to 300 ns.
- `y` in the range from 1 to 6
- `z` in the range from 0 to 7

For the example below I create some random test data.

I can reproduce your issue with `splot ... with pm3d`, however, do not (yet) have a solution.
Therefore, my suggestion would be to use `plot ... with boxxerror`.
If you plot that many boxes, your PostScript file probably will get pretty large. So, I would recommend to use a pixel graphic with sufficient resolution, e.g. `set term pngacairo size 1400,1000`.

**Code:**

```
### "plot ... with boxxyerror" instead of "splot ... with pm3d"
reset session

set palette maxcolors 8
set palette defined (0 "#FFFFFF",  1 "#FFFF00",  2 "#FFC020",  3 "#FF69B4",  4 "#4169E1",  5 "#008000",  6 "#20B2AA",  7 "#9ACD32")

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:7500] for [j=1:5] {
        print sprintf("%g %g %g", i, int(rand(0)*6)+(j-1)*7+2, int(rand(0)*8))
    }
set print

set xrange [0:300]
XScale = 300/7500.     # scaling between sample and x-axis units

set yrange [1: 37]
set for [i=1:5] ytics (sprintf("%g",i) i*7-2)
set ytics nomirror

set y2range [1: 37]
set for [i=1:5] y2tics ("1" i*7-5, "7" i*7+1)
set y2tics nomirror
set link y2

set cbrange [-0.500: 7.500]
set cbtics 0.000, 7.000, 1.0
myCbTics = "None Ext Bridge 3-10 Alpha Pi Turn Bend"
set for [i=0:words(myCbTics)] cbtics (word(myCbTics,i+1) i)

set key noautotitle
set tics out
set style fill solid 1.0

plot $Data u ($1*XScale):2:($1*XScale):(($1+1)*XScale):($2):($2+1):3 w boxxy palette z
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Sir, everything else works but a blank plot with all the labelling is generated if I try to replace the random data points with data from the file '-' (as before) following the code.

Comment: @Madhusmita Have you ended the inline data with `e` ? Alternatively, is your data in a file? Then try `plot 'yourFilename.dat' u ($1*XScale):2:($1*XScale):(($1+1)*XScale):($2):($2+1):3 w boxxy palette z`

Comment: Yes, tried both ways but it isn't working.

Comment: @Madhusmita what does "isn't working" mean? Error messages, empty plot, others...? Can you provide some more data?

Comment: Yes sir empty plot with all the axes and labels present but no data.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my previous data points and also added some random data.

Comment: @Madhusmita I don't know what you are doing differently. If I take your most recent data fragment, and add it to my code and adjust `set xrange[0:1]` I see some colored boxes. Instead of the lines generating random data in the code above you can add a line `$Data <<EOD`,  copy your data after that and add a line `EOD`.

Comment: Sir it worked. Neither 'e' nor 'end of data' was working but as I replaced it with 'EOD' the plot was well generated. Thank you so much for all the help, patience and time.

Comment: @Madhusmita glad to hear that it now seems to work for you. Don't forget to accept the answer (check the checkmark next to the answer) indicating that it solved your problem and upvote if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Sure Sir. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the default link command `set link y2` is failing, but it seems to work if you explicitly give the longer form `set link y2 via y inv y`.

Aside from that, note that `set link y2` command will immediately replace any limits on `y2range` with limits matching the `y1` range, so the `set y2range` command in your script as shown has no effect.

Comment: For me (gnuplot 5.2.8, Windows), `set link y2 via y inv y` does not create all y2tics, but like in OP's question. Especially when I start the code with a `reset session` in order to reset some earlier settings. However, in the wxt terminal it will shows all y2tics after I scroll down the graph and up again with the mouse.